Redux-saga catch error and display notification
I'm facing an issue and I'm looking for the best solution to fix it. I want to display a notification on my dashboard in case of an error. To achieve this:
I'm using Redux-Saga to catch the error and store it in my reducer as shown below:
agencySaga.js
export function* getAgencies() {
  try {
    const agencies = yield call(getAgenciesService);
    const data = agencies?.data;
    if (data) {
      yield put(getAgenciesAction.success(agencies.data));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(getAgenciesAction.failure(err));
  }
}

agencyReducer.js
import { AGENCIES, AGENCIESDETAILS, AGENCY } from '../actions/agencyAction';
import formatErrorMessage from '../utils/errorMessage';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  agencies: null, agenciesDetails: null, message: null, loading: false,
};

const agencyReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case AGENCIES.FETCH.REQUEST:
      return { ...state, loading: true, message: null };
    case AGENCIES.FETCH.SUCCESS:
      return {...state, agencies: payload, loading: false, message: null };
    case AGENCIES.FETCH.FAILURE:
      return { ...state, loading: false, message: formatErrorMessage(payload, 'agencies') };

Then, I display the notification on my dashboard.
Dashboard.jsx
const { agencies, loading, message } = useSelector((state) => state.agencies);

useEffect(() => {
  if (message) {
    notification.error({
      message: message.title,
      description: message.description,
    });
  }
}, [message]);

Problem Simulation:

Case 1: The API is not accessible, we enter the saga's catch block, the message in the store is updated, and the notification is displayed on the dashboard. Everything works fine.

Case 2: The API is accessible. I refresh the page, and the initial render still displays the notification because the message in the store is still set until AGENCIES.FETCH.REQUEST and AGENCIES.FETCH.SUCCESS are triggered to reset the message to null.


The problem seems to be with this useEffect because i tried this method as shown below, it works, but it's not the result I'm looking for. I want to display my notification.
Dashboard.jsx
return (
  <PageContainer className="dashboard" screenHeight={window.innerHeight}>
    <AgenciesDetails />
    {message && <div>{message.title}</div>}
    {renderComponentsList()}
  </PageContainer>
);

Do you have any solutions to fix this problem while adhering to best practices?

You could clear the message state after the notification is triggered.
Example Implementation:
agencyReducer.js
const agencyReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case AGENCIES.FETCH.REQUEST:
      return { ...state, loading: true, message: null };

    case AGENCIES.FETCH.SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        agencies: payload,
        loading: false,
        message: null,
      };

    case AGENCIES.FETCH.FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        message: formatErrorMessage(payload, 'agencies')
      };

    case AGENCIES.FETCH.CLEAR_MESSAGE:
      return { ...state, message: null };

    ...
  }
};

"getAgenciesAction"
const clearMessage = () => ({
  type: AGENCIES.FETCH.CLEAR_MESSAGE
});

Dashboard.jsx
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const { agencies, loading, message } = useSelector((state) => state.agencies);

useEffect(() => {
  if (message) {
    notification.error({
      message: message.title,
      description: message.description,
    });
    dispatch(getAgenciesAction.clearMessage());
  }
}, [dispatch, message]);

If you didn't want to clear the message state because you want the error to persist until success you can similarly use some state the represents having triggered the notification, setting it "shown" when the notification is triggered, and resetting it "unshown" at the next success or failure.
If notification is a global reference you might even be able to trigger it directly from the saga.
Example:
import formatErrorMessage from '../utils/errorMessage';
import notification from '../path/to/notification';

export function* getAgencies() {
  try {
    const agencies = yield call(getAgenciesService);
    const data = agencies?.data;
    if (data) {
      yield put(getAgenciesAction.success(agencies.data));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    const message = formatErrorMessage(err);
    notification.error({
      message: message.title,
      description: message.description,
    });
    yield put(getAgenciesAction.failure(err));
  }
}


Great, thank you very much for your time! The three solutions are interesting, I will study them more closely.

Yes, I tried these three suggestions. I used the situation with the notification display directly from the saga's catch error; it meets my needs a bit better. Thank you !
